# Thread DSL behavior with queue in camel

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-camel

With below route i expect that 10 msg from `queue1`should be process concurrently, but only one gets process at a time.

**Am i expecting wrong ? or doing something wrong ?**

```
context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {                                       
            from("test-jms:queue:test.queue1").threads(10)
            .process(sleep(1)); // sleep id is 1                
        }

        private Processor sleep(final int sleepId) {
            return new Processor() {                    
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {                       
                    System.out.println(curTime() + " Going for sleep sleepid=" + sleepId );
                    Thread.sleep(5000l);                        
                    System.out.println(curTime() + " Done sleep sleepid=" + sleepId );
                }
            };
        }
```

Calling the above routes using:

```
   ExecutorService ec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    ec.submit(new Task(context,template));
    ec.submit(new Task(context,template));
    ec.submit(new Task(context,template));
    ec.submit(new Task(context,template));
    ec.submit(new Task(context,template));

static class Task  implements Runnable{
    CamelContext context;
    ProducerTemplate template;
    public Task(CamelContext context, ProducerTemplate template) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.template = template;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {         
           Exchange exchange = new DefaultExchange(context);
           exchange.setPattern(ExchangePattern.InOnly);
           exchange.getIn().setBody("Test Message: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
           System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
           Exchange send = template.send("test-jms:queue:test.queue1",exchange);
           System.out.println("completed");           
    }

}
```

OutPut from code:

```
10:24:11 Going for sleep sleepid=1
10:24:16 Done sleep sleepid=1

10:24:16 Going for sleep sleepid=1
10:24:21 Done sleep sleepid=1

10:24:21 Going for sleep sleepid=1
10:24:26 Done sleep sleepid=1

10:24:26 Going for sleep sleepid=1
10:24:31 Done sleep sleepid=1

10:24:31 Going for sleep sleepid=1
10:24:36 Done sleep sleepid=1
```

If we observe the timestamp we will see that route is only processing 1 msg at time.

Comment: http://camel.apache.org/jms.html provides a setting "concurrentConsumers" ... so does this shows that thread dsl is not supported by jms endpoint ? .. even if i am using INONLY exchange pattern...

Comment: If I understood this correctly, you want it to process all 10 of the messages to sleep at the same time, right?

Comment: @Itrollin yes , correct

Comment: Yes better to just have concurrentConsumers=10 in the jms endpoint and then no threads is needed.

Comment: claus Ibsen .. above case is for my learning camel, so is it correct to say that its upto endpoint which all DSL it will support ? If yes, is it documented somewhere .... just curious why jms endpoint does not support threads DSL

Comment: @ClausIbsen please read above comment

Comment: Read about the asyncConsumer option on the JMS doc

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable `asyncConsumer` on the JMS endpoint to allow it to be async. When doing this then messages consumed from the queue can be processed out of order, and hence why a consumer is ordered by default.

The code should be

```
 public void configure() {                                       
            from("test-jms:queue:test.queue1?asyncConsumer=true").threads(10)
            .process(sleep(1)); // sleep id is 1                
        }
```

But the JMS component has built-in concurrency which is usually better to use, as then it can use concurrent JMS consumers, and concurrent networking. See the options `concurrentConsumers` and `maxConcurrentConsumers` for more details.

Comment: So does that mean it is correct to say that its upto endpoint that will it support a particular DSL... If yes, it is not documented well that which endpoint support which DSL